# Problema con mi app flutter en play store

Tags: sdk

Estoy intentando subir una actualización de mi app a play store pero me la han rechazado por causa del siguiente problema. revise las instalaciones pero no la llamo directamente y actualize las versiones pero aun asi me la siguen rechazando.

Problema encontrado: violación de la política de datos del usuario
Revisamos los SDK utilizados por su aplicación y encontramos versiones no compatibles de los SDK que recopilan identificadores persistentes de dispositivos. Los identificadores de dispositivos persistentes no pueden vincularse a otros datos personales y confidenciales del usuario ni a identificadores de dispositivos reiniciables.

Detalles del problema

Encontramos un problema en las siguientes áreas:

Código de versión 2 :
SDK: Cardinal Commerce org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk (considere actualizar a la versión 2.2.7-2)
Además, siga estos pasos para que su aplicación cumpla con los requisitos:

Puede considerar actualizar a una versión de este SDK que cumpla con las políticas, si está disponible a través de su proveedor de SDK, o eliminar el SDK.
Acerca de la política de datos del usuario
Limitar el acceso, la recopilación, el uso y el intercambio de datos personales y confidenciales del usuario adquiridos a través de la aplicación a la funcionalidad de la aplicación y el servicio y a los fines que cumplan con las políticas razonablemente esperados por el usuario.

Los identificadores de dispositivos persistentes no pueden vincularse a otros datos personales y confidenciales del usuario ni a identificadores de dispositivos reiniciables, excepto para los siguientes fines:

Telefonía vinculada a una identidad SIM (por ejemplo, llamadas wifi vinculadas a una cuenta de operador), y
Aplicaciones de administración de dispositivos empresariales que utilizan el modo propietario del dispositivo.
Estos usos deben divulgarse de manera destacada a los usuarios como se especifica en la política de Datos del usuario. Consulte este recurso para obtener identificadores únicos alternativos.